# cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'float' Unity CS0029

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private new Rigidbody rigidbody;

    public float speed = 10f;

    bool isJump = false;
    public float JumpForce = 5.0f;
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (hor != 0.0f || ver != 0.0f)
        {
            Vector3 dir = transform.forward * ver + transform.right * hor;

            rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + dir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        JumpForce = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

        if (isJump)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector4(0, JumpForce, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happening

Comment: Can you share the full error message? What line of code does it relate to?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get and mark the location where you get the error message.

Comment: `Input.GetButtonDown()` is returning a `bool` value, but `JumpForce` is of type `float`, see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html

Answer (score 1):

This line should be changed from:
JumpForce = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");

To:
isJump = Input.GetButtonDown("Jump");